# How can I rewrite urls to ignore sub-directories?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this url:

http://www.example.com/some-annoying-folder/page.html?name=stack+overflow

But the file is actually located in the root directory and should look like this:

http://www.example.com/page.html?name=stack+overflow

Furthermore, there are similar sub-directories that need to be modified also.

As much as I use htaccess, I still am having a hard time getting used to it.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Update:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteRule .*(schedule.html|tickets.html|venue.html|city.html|concerts.html)$ $1 [L,R=302,QSA,NC]

#BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
#END WordPress
```

Comment: By the way, it's an external script that's generating the urls so I cannot modify that; I'm looking for the re-write solution.

Comment: Is some-annoying-folder always the same?

Comment: The file, page.html is supposed to be located in the root directory but the links are being generated with sub directories.

Comment: Is page.html the only page for which this is happening? The whole trick with using .htaccess for this type of stuff is to identify what is consistent and what isn't, then work on a pattern to capture what is consistent.

Comment: There are 4 or 5 files that this is happening to.  So we need to take these 5 files and ignore any folder before them.

Comment: OK .. continuing in an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given additional input by OP - suppose page1.html and page2.html are two files that have non-existent directories prepended to them. This rule will fix that:

```
RewriteRule .*(page1.html|page2.html)$ $1 [L,R=302,QSA,NC]
```

If you have more such files, you can simply add them in there separated by `|` as above.

**EDIT** modified rule with more information:

```
RewriteRule .+/(schedule.html|tickets.html|venue.html|city.html|concerts.html)$ $1 [L,R=302,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't working.  I used the code exactly like you put it.  Does it matter that there is more url after the filename in the url... page.html?name=stack+overflow

Comment: No that shouldn't matter. The part after ? is carried over as it is. Did you replace page1.html in my rule with page.html? page1.html and page2.html are just placeholders for whatever pages you have that this is happening to. I checked - the rule works.

Comment: Yes, I changed those to the file names.

Comment: Yes it's possible other .htaccess code is interfering - see where above? Move these rules as far to the top as you can. after RewriteEngine on.

Comment: Yes I see where the interference is. Do you want Wordpress to handle these pages or no?

Comment: they are pages in the wordpress database so i guess so.

Comment: Awesome... You Rock!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This should work with Apache:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/subfolder/$ http://www.example.com/
```

Comment: Can't seem to get this working...
    RedirectMatch 301 ^/subfolder/$ http://www.example.com/